# Container.Verify throws System.ExecutionEngineException sometimes

Tags: simple-injector

This problem occurs locally only, on a WCF based web api project running in IISExpress. 
It happens fairly randomly.

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in SimpleInjector.dll"

This occurs when I do container.Verify()

Any ideas what might cause this, or how to debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ExecutionEngineException` is usually caused by profiling tools such as:

- Microsoft IntelliTrace
- JetBrains dotTrace

But I've seen this been caused by Microsoft's test runner (MSTest) as well.

Limitations (or flaws) in those tools, cause them to be unable to cope with dynamic assembly compilation. Dynamic assembly compilation is what Simple Injector uses to optimize performance.

The most effective way to deal with this (without having to change anything to the profiling or testing tools that you use) is to disable Simple Injector's dynamic assembly compilation as follows:

```
container.Options.EnableDynamicAssemblyCompilation = false;
```

This means that the delegates that Simple Injector will compile will be created using Lightweight Code Generation (which is slightly slower, but nothing to worry about) instead of creating a new in-memory assembly.

Another option is to disable tools like IntelliTrace or dotTrace, but this isn't always an option of course. In case of MSTest, you can also disable its 'Keep Test Execution Engine Running' functionality.

> Side note: There's an [old issue](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/workitem/20677) on the old Codeplex site that describes the problem and the solution. Unfortunately, due to many mistakes by the Codeplex team, this issue can't be found by Googling, and the issue has become unreadable over time.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try that. This doesn't occur when running under a profiling tool just "normal" iisexpress launching sometimes seems to kill it. If it works, then the issue would be that I probably don't want the above option disabled in my production code (as I only ever see this in dev).

Comment: It does seem to be related to Dynamic compilation. I managed to analyze in windbg and it seems to be EF DbContext related during verify.

Comment: On further debugging it doesn't seem to be a specific type that causes it. The common factor seems to be that it occurs after a recompile, which in turn would shut down the web app. It seems to be on the call after the recompile it happens. So possibly something to do with IISExpress still being alive but the application being restarted?